# Can I block specific imports that match regex with vite?

Tags: vite

In my source code, i'm regrouping everything by features. So I can have server and client code in the same folder. Is it possible to tell vite to rise an error if I import a server script inside my client code ?

For example I plan to name everything related to client `authentication.client.ts` and everything related to the server `authentication.server.ts`. Is it possible tell vite to reject everything that match `*.server.*` ?